# Prove the set, {y ∈ X | r ≤ d(x,y) ≤ s}, is closed

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let r < s be positive real numbers and x ∈ X. Prove that the set:

```
    {y ∈ X | r ≤ d(x,y) ≤ s},
```

is closed.

Having trouble with how I should tackle this question. Do I prove the compliment is open? If so, how would I?

Comment: Do you believe in closed balls and open balls? You could make it the intersection of a closed ball with the complement of an open ball: a closed set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed $x_0 \in X$, then $f(y)=d(x_0,y)$ is a continuous function( you can actually show it is Lipschitz continuous). Then your set is just preimage of a closed set of $\mathbb{R}$ under a continuous function, which is closed.

Or you can show its complement is open, which is a union of two open sets.

Answer (score 0):

If $d$ is a metric of space $X$, the the conclusion is right. Since $d$ is continuous and the set is equal to  $d^{-1}([r,s])$. Note that for a continuous function, any inverse images of closed sets are closed.

Answer (score 0):

A closed set contains its limit points.
To prove that we need to show that the set, $\{y ∈ X | r ≤ d(x,y) ≤ s\}$, contains its limit points $r$ and $s$.

This is obvious since any open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $r$ or $s$ will have a nonempty intersection with both the set and the complement of the set $\forall$ $\epsilon>0$.
Thus, it can be proved that the set contains its limit points and hence it is closed.